# Rspec not executing AJAX calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, selenium, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to test a link that calls a controller action using ajax. Essentially, when the user clicks on "Follow", he will be associated with the company and a render partial will be executed with JS. 
The problem is that it works correctly when I try it in development, but it does not respond in the tests. I've been trying in a lots of ways, and it looks that the call never gets to the controller.

Here you can see the test:

```
#spec/integration/following_spec.rb

it "should add the company to the ones followed by the user", :js => true do
  find("#current_company").click_link "Follow"
  sleep 2
  @user.companies_followed.include?(@company).should be_true
end
```

The view:

```
#app/views/companies/_follow_button.html.slim

= link_to change_follow_state_company_path(@company), :method => :put, :remote => true, :id => "follow", :class => "btn_block light" do
' Follow
```

And the test configuration:

```
#spec/integration_helper.rb

require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/integration/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.before do
    clear_email_queue
  end
end

Rails.cache.clear
```

Comment: @Gawyn : did you find a solution for this? me also having the same issue..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to take into account that isn't RSpec who is trying to make that AJAX call but capybara.

Also, what Rails is doing with that `method: :put` and `remote: true` is using UJS, which capybara with `rack/test` doesn't handle well out-of-the-box (because it implies javascript). That would probably also be true if you weren't even using `remote: true` but only `method: :put`.

I bet if you use capybara-webkit that won't happen:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'capybara-webkit'

# spec/integration_helper.rb
Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
```

If that works, is `rack/test` what's giving you the problem. That's because it isn't so good when dealing with javascript. In cucumber there's something called `capybara_javascript_emulation` but I wouldn't rely on that when doing the tests.

My approach: Switch the driver on tests that need javascript and rely on the naive `rack-test` on simpler ones :)

Also, use `spinach`, for god's sake! (or `turnip`, at least) :D

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer @josepjaume! I have been trying your approach, but to no avail: it's still the same. :(

Comment: Seriously? Even when using `capybara-webkit` or `selenity`?

Comment: No luck with capybara-webkit. I also tried with selenium, but nothing.